# Congruences - proof problems

Tags: modular-arithmetic, congruences

**1)** State what is meant by $a\equiv b \pmod n$.

**2)** Suppose that $a\equiv b \pmod n$ and $c\equiv d \pmod n$. Prove that

> **i)** $a+c\equiv b+d \pmod n$
>
> **ii)** $ac\equiv bd \pmod n$

For question 1, I would state that $n|(a-b)$

For part ii, I would simply use algebraic manipulation to get the desired result but i don't think I'm proving it.

Comment: For part ii, algebraic manipulation is fine.  If you want to show exactly what you did and where you are stuck, I'm sure someone will be able to help you.

Comment: For part 1, I would say $a = kn + b$ for some $k \in \Bbb Z$, and this should help in part 2.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a = k_1n + b$ and $c = k_2n + d$, $k_1, k_2 \in \Bbb Z$. Then
$$
a+c = k_1n + b + k_2n + d = (k_1+k_2)n + (b+d)\\
ac = (k_1n+b)(k_2n+d) = (k_1k_2n+k_1d+k_2b)n+bd$$

Answer (score 1):

If $m$ divides $a,b;m$  must divide $ax+by$ where $x,y$ are arbitrary integers

For the first, $$a+c-(b+d)=(a-b)+(c-d)$$

For the second, $$ac-bd=a(c-d)+d(a-b)$$

Answer (score 0):

1) is perfect.

For 2i) use your definition: if $n|a-b$ and $n|c-d$ then $n|(a-b) + (c-d) = (a+c)-(b+d)$.

For 2ii) you can very well try the same kind of proof. Can you try it yourself?

Comment: you are right. But I guess it is just a typo, as there is no $c$ in question 1.

Comment: just a typo there